# jquery validation for address field

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

There are three text fields for the address. I need the jQuery validation to check if the first field is filled, submit the data, or when second field is filled, check the first field. If it is empty, display error message, or if 3rd field is filled, check 1st and 2nd fields. If they are empty, display error message, or if first 2 fields are filled, submit the data.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
      $.validator.addMethod("address_fields", function(value, element) {
        if( $(value).val()=="#address_line_4")
        {
            if($(value).val() != "")
            {
                if( $("#address_line_3").val()!="" && $("#address_line_2").val()!="" && $("#address_line_1").val()!="")
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
       else if($(value).val()=="#address_line_3")
       {   
           if( $("#address_line_3").val()!="")
            {
                     if( $("#address_line_2").val()!="" &&  $("#address_line_1").val()!="")
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

            }
        }
       else if( $(value).val()=="#address_line_2")
       {
           if( $("#address_line_2").val()!="")
           {
                if( $("#address_line_1").val()!="")
             {
                 return true;
             }
           }
       }
      },"Please enter the Home Address");

    });
```

Comment: Did you tried something ? Please show us your code so that we will be able to help you.

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address_line_1" id="address_line_1" />                                                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address_line_2" id="address_line_2" />                                                                                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address_line_3" id="address_line_3" />                                                                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address_line_4" id="address_line_4" />..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qCJ8T/.. it works